# Cordova InAppBrowser Unable to open local HTML file

Tags: android, cordova, inappbrowser

I am trying to open a bundled html page from within the InAppBrowser using the following code

```
 var optionStr = 'location=no,clearcache=yes';

 console.log('optionStr-->' + optionStr);

 window.open('owp/index.html', '_blank', optionStr);
```

But when I run this on my Android device I get the following error on my Console

```
 04-10 15:04:52.193: E/Web Console(15947): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'NONE' of undefined:24
```

Could anyone please help me out here ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you missed something, replace with the below,

Instead of using three lines you can directly use recommended method,

```
var optionStr = window.open("yourHTMLPage.html", "_blank", "location=yes");
```

Also, your Console Error message not belongs to the given code, locate the 'NONE' somewhere else.
Hope this helps.